# mysql sort all records except for the one that have specific flag

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Here is my query

```
select o.orders_id, o.employee_name,o.payment_method,
o.currency_value, o.order_ref_number,o.orders_status,o.remaining_qty, 
s.orders_status_name, ot.value as order_total,
sum( op.products_quantity ) as num_pieces from orders o 
left join orders_total ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id) 
left join orders_products op on ( o.orders_id = op.orders_id ) 
left join customers c on c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
left join customers_groups cg using(customers_group_id), orders_status s 
where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '1' 
and s.orders_status_id !=17 and ot.class = 'ot_total'
group by o.orders_id 
order by o.employee_name, o.target_ship_date, o.customers_name
```

the output of this query is
[image]

What I want to achieve is to show all the records that have **orders_status**=1 on top and then order the remaining records by **employee_name** (currently ordering on the basis of this field)

I need the ordering by **employee name** except for the ones that have orders_status = 1 (which will be on the top)

thanks

Comment: Use 

ORDER BY o.orders_status, o.employee_name, o.target_ship_date, o.customers_name

first put o.orders_status in ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Muhammad Asif Raza check my answer please, is it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `order_status = 1 desc,` before `employee_name`:

```
SELECT o.orders_id, 
       o.employee_name, 
       o.payment_method, 
       o.currency_value, 
       o.order_ref_number, 
       o.orders_status, 
       o.remaining_qty, 
       s.orders_status_name, 
       ot.value                  AS order_total, 
       Sum(op.products_quantity) AS num_pieces 
FROM   orders o 
       LEFT JOIN orders_total ot 
              ON ( o.orders_id = ot.orders_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN orders_products op 
              ON ( o.orders_id = op.orders_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN customers c 
              ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
       LEFT JOIN customers_groups cg USING(customers_group_id), 
       orders_status s 
WHERE  o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
       AND s.language_id = '1' 
       AND s.orders_status_id != 17 
       AND ot.class = 'ot_total' 
GROUP  BY o.orders_id 
ORDER  BY ( o.order_status = 1 ) DESC, 
          o.employee_name, 
          o.target_ship_date, 
          o.customers_name
```

***Edit:***

```
SELECT o.orders_id, 
       o.employee_name, 
       o.payment_method, 
       o.currency_value, 
       o.order_ref_number, 
       o.orders_status, 
       o.remaining_qty, 
       s.orders_status_name, 
       ot.value                  AS order_total, 
       Sum(op.products_quantity) AS num_pieces 
FROM   orders o 
       LEFT JOIN orders_total ot 
              ON ( o.orders_id = ot.orders_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN orders_products op 
              ON ( o.orders_id = op.orders_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN customers c 
              ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
       LEFT JOIN customers_groups cg USING(customers_group_id), 
       orders_status s 
WHERE  o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
       AND s.language_id = '1' 
       AND s.orders_status_id != 17 
       AND ot.class = 'ot_total' 
GROUP  BY o.orders_id 
ORDER  BY ( o.order_status = 1 ) DESC, 
          o.employee_name + 0, 
          o.target_ship_date, 
          o.customers_name
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

It orders all the orders_status = 1 records on top but the remaining records that should be ordered according to employee_name are not ordered properly..

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza Have you ever run this?

Comment: your answer is not working for employee_name ordering. orders that have orders_status=1 are now on top but the remaining (which should be ordered according to employee_name column)are not ordering properly.. it is displaying all employee_name which are 10 then 11 then 12 and then 3. which is wrong

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza Nope, if your `employee_name` is varchar or text, then this order is right, or if the `employee_name` are all numbers, and you want to sort them by digit number, please check ***edit*** part. You should google the difference between text order and digit order.

Comment: now the edited answer is working perfectly :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go with a union since orders_status are more than 2.

```
select [...]
from [multiple joins]
where orders_status = 1
order by empolyee name

UNION

select [...]
from [multiple joins]
where orders_status <> 1
order by employee name
```

If there were only 2 status (let's say 1 for successfull and 0 for failed) you could have just ordered by orders_status and then name

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE1, if you don't want to use employee name when orders_status = 1:

```
select 
    o.orders_id, 
    o.employee_name,
    o.payment_method,
    o.currency_value, 
    o.order_ref_number,
    o.orders_status,
    o.remaining_qty, 
    s.orders_status_name, 
    ot.value as order_total,
    sum( op.products_quantity ) as num_pieces 
from orders o 
    left join orders_total ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id) 
    left join orders_products op on ( o.orders_id = op.orders_id ) 
    left join customers c on c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
    left join customers_groups cg using(customers_group_id), orders_status s 
where 
    o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
    and s.language_id = '1' 
    and s.orders_status_id !=17 
    and ot.class = 'ot_total'
group by o.orders_id 
order by 
    case
        when o.orders_status = 1 then 0
        else 1
    end asc,
    case
        when o.orders_status <> 1 then o.employee_name
    end asc,
    o.target_ship_date, o.customers_name
```

Comment: your answer is not working for employee_name ordering. orders that have orders_status=1 are now on top but the remaining (which should be ordered according to employee_name column)are not ordering.. it is displaying all employee_name which are 10 then 11 then 12 and then 3. which is wrong

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza what data type in this column you have? If it's varchar f.e., than ordering completely okay.

Comment: the employee_name is integer